# MS Project: Percentage of elapsed work time of project

Tags: ms-project, progress-monitor

Suppose we have a project, that its progress is not going exactly on the plan (e.g. we have worked on some future tasks and some previous tasks are not completed on the schedule). and also some previous tasks have been interrupted for a while and these interruptions demonstrated in tasks using "ms project split" feature. these interruptions are not supposed to be calculated as missed time in the project.

Now we know how much work has been done using "% Work Complete", but my question is that how can we determine how much of Project Work time has been passed? exactly:
(times we worked on previous tasks + times we missed to work in previous tasks - interruptions - nonworking times)/(whole duration of project)

Edit: if we do nothing through project, "% Work Complete" would not grows, but percentage of elapsed work time would grow to 100% until end of plan time disregard how much project has been progressed. So comparing these two parameters should tel us, how the project is going to be ended on time.

I've written this formula for Custom Field to find ratio of elapsed calendar:

```
ProjDateDiff([Start],Now())/[Duration]
```

I'm not sure if this returns right value for ratio of elapsed calendar, but even for right value for sure it does not consider effect of "Interruption" and "NON-Working Times" in the ratio.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Percent Complete is a duration measure that will compare actual duration and remaining duration.  Unless you are using Fixed Duration tasks, the time in the split does not change the duration.

Comment: Actually I'm not very familiar with MSP and PM, but I think "Actual Duration" is the duration that the team have worked on the project.

So if we do nothing in the next week the "Actual Duration" would not change after the week, but we have missed one working week and "%Elapsed Time" (with above definition) should grow. 

Then Comparing %Elapsed Time and %Work Complete would tel us how we did well in project.

Comment: True - but you shouldn't leave any incomplete work in the past.  So, if you have baselined the project, you should be able to see variance (start, finish) after rescheduling the incomplete work.